# Invertible matrix and determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

I am studying for my exam and I am stuck in the following problem:

Let $A$ be an $r × r$ real valued matrix, and $I$ be the r × r identity matrix.

1. Prove that if the entries of A satisfy $$ \sum_{j=1}^r |A_{ij} | < 1$$ for each $i = 1, 2, \ldots, r$, then $I + A$ is invertible. I have no idea how to do this one.
2. Prove that if $A$ satisfies $A^T = −A$, then $det(aI + A) \neq 0$ for all $a ∈ R - \{0\}$.

For this I have tried contradiction; suppose that $det(aI + A) = 0$ which means that it is singular. Therefore we have a non zero $x$ such that  $(aI + A)x = 0$.

$\implies ax+Ax=0 \implies ax^T+x^T A^T =0 \implies ax^T-x^T A =0 \implies ax^T x -x^T A x =0 $.

This means we have $ax^T x -x^T A x =0$ and $ax^T x +x^T A x =0$. Simplying gives $2ax^T x=0 \implies x=0$. Which is a contradiction.

Comment: In part 1, prove that the spectral radius of $A$ is smaller than $1$. In part 2, prove that $aI+A$ is nonsingular by considering $x^T(aI+A)x$ for any nonzero real vector $x$.

Comment: Suppose $Ax+x = 0$ for some $x \neq 0$. Suppose $x_i $ is a component of $x$ that has maximum modulus. Then
$|x_i| = |\sum_{k} A_{ik} x_k|\le \sum_{k} |A_{ik}| |x_i| < |x_i|$.

Comment: @user1551 I have edited part 2. Could you please check it?

Comment: @copper.hat I got what you said but I dont understand how can I use it? Could you please explain a little more?

Comment: It proves that $I+A$ is invertible.

Comment: @copper.hat I still dont understand what the inequality says.

Comment: I shows that there is no $x \neq 0$ that satisfies $Ax+x = 0$.

Comment: @copper.hat I think the inequality part is the contradiction. If yes then could you explain it a little? Also for part 2 is my solution correct ?

Comment: Your answer to part 2 looks fine.